# Develop smart applications for Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'm looking to create a very -tiny- application(s) in Windows 7. I'm looking for a programming language like C# and a simple framework that

- Makes the application very light weight
- Doesn't require any libraries or modules (only the *.exe and works on a newly installed Win7)
- The IDE (Or the compiler) let me easily implement windows 7 features (like the menu, the graphics...)

**The point**: I want to create a small application (light weight so it can be easily transported), that focus mainly on Windows 7 graphic design and features.

I don't know if such IDE exists but also asking how will you solve it, mean if you have to create a tiny application (gadget like) how will you proceed?

Comment: You can't create light-weigth apps in any .NET language, because they require the framework an CLR to run.  You will need to use something like C, and if you're careful, C++ using some kind of lightweight runtime library that can be statically linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Lightweight and regarding dependencies: Well, since you want kind of C#, you have the .NET Framework. That's not exactly lightweight, unless you're sure that the target system has it available. Be sure to check which .NET version comes preinstalled with Seven. *Addendum: Now that 7 is out, it seems it comes preinstalled with .NET 3.5 SP1 (full framework, not client profile). That's a good thing.*
- Have a look at the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) for Windows 7 for access to Windows 7 features. Like tvanfosson, I'd also stick with Visual Studio and .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd stick with Visual Studio.  You might want to get a utility like [NuGenUnify](http://www.genetibase.com/cforce/nugenunify.php), which makes it easy to use ILMerge to combine any extra libraries into the main exe if you want to distribute as a single file.

Comment: I'm going to create a small app, don't you think Visual Studio + WPF (since I want them interactive) will be very complicated and a long time to learn

Comment: While I like it, you don't need WPF for interactive applications. Windows Forms is fine for many applications. If you need something fancy, you can go with custom controls.

Comment: Longer than what?  Win32 API? Java/Swing? If you want to develop in C#, VS is the way to go IMO.  Whether you decide to use WPF or WinForms.  You might want look some gadget development projects on CodeProject for some ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/?cat=20

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't seen any other IDE that beats Visual Studio for windows app development. Especially soon after a Windows release. I'd be surprised if I am proved to be wrong.